# LDAP filter using where

Tags: python, sql, filter, ldap

Is it possible to ask the OpenLDAP sever something like I would do it in a SQL query: select * from table where modified < last_modified?
What I am trying to achieve is export some data based on attribute values of each entry in LDAP where an entry has the attributes: modified and last_modified. What I need is a list of these entries and their attributes. I am not sure if it is possible or how to achieve this. I am using Python ldap3 module to query the LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in most LDAP Server Implementations, retrieve this with a LDAP searchFilter similar to:

```
(modifytimestamp<=20180301000000Z)
```

To be clear this will return the LDAP Entries which have been modified.
The attributes returned is up to you to specify for searchAttribute. For all User Attributes "*" and for all User Attributes and Operational  attributes "+".

The filter must be surrounded by parentheses.